# Rails 4: Joins vs Includes: Why different results with nested association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 4 app, I have two models:

Merchant has_many :offering_specials

OfferingSpecial belongs_to :merchant

I want to retrieve all merchants and their special offerings that are open (with the status_code: "OP")

I tried this:

```
@merchants = Merchant.joins(:offering_specials).where(offering_specials: { status_code: "OP" })
```

This is the query:

```
Merchant Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `merchants`.* FROM `merchants` INNER JOIN `offering_specials` ON `offering_specials`.`merchant_id` = `merchants`.`id` WHERE `offering_specials`.`status_code` = 'OP'
```

But it retrieved all offering specials, both the open ("OP") and the pending ("PN").

However, using includes worked:

```
@merchants = Merchant.joins(:offering_specials).where(offering_specials: { status_code: "OP" })
```

This retrieved only the open offering specials.  But look at the much slower query:

```
  SQL (19.9ms)  SELECT `merchants`.`id` AS t0_r0, `merchants`.`name` AS t0_r1, `merchants`.`slug` AS t0_r2, `merchants`.`url` AS t0_r3, `merchants`.`summary` AS t0_r4, `merchants`.`description` AS t0_r5, `merchants`.`active_for_display` AS t0_r6, `merchants`.`active_for_offerings_by_merchant` AS t0_r7, `merchants`.`active_for_offerings_by_legatocard` AS t0_r8, `merchants`.`credit_limit` AS t0_r9, `merchants`.`search_location_code` AS t0_r10, `merchants`.`image_file_name` AS t0_r11, `merchants`.`image_file_size` AS t0_r12, `merchants`.`image_content_type` AS t0_r13, `merchants`.`image_updated_at` AS t0_r14, `merchants`.`logo_file_name` AS t0_r15, `merchants`.`logo_file_size` AS t0_r16, `merchants`.`logo_content_type` AS t0_r17, `merchants`.`logo_updated_at` AS t0_r18, `merchants`.`created_at` AS t0_r19, `merchants`.`updated_at` AS t0_r20, `offering_specials`.`id` AS t1_r0, `offering_specials`.`special_number` AS t1_r1, `offering_specials`.`merchant_id` AS t1_r2, `offering_specials`.`merchant_user_id` AS t1_r3, `offering_specials`.`nonprofit_percentage` AS t1_r4, `offering_specials`.`discount_percentage` AS t1_r5, `offering_specials`.`start_at` AS t1_r6, `offering_specials`.`end_at` AS t1_r7, `offering_specials`.`closed_at` AS t1_r8, `offering_specials`.`max_dollar_amount_for_offering` AS t1_r9, `offering_specials`.`max_dollar_amount_per_buyer` AS t1_r10, `offering_specials`.`status_code` AS t1_r11, `offering_specials`.`created_at` AS t1_r12, `offering_specials`.`updated_at` AS t1_r13 FROM `merchants` LEFT OUTER JOIN `offering_specials` ON `offering_specials`.`merchant_id` = `merchants`.`id` WHERE `offering_specials`.`status_code` = 'OP'
```

How can I get get this query to work with a joins, instead of the includes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries of this sort do not normally return associated records. You're requesting a list of Merchants, and that's what you get. When you subsequently request the associated OfferingSpecials of one of those Merchants, a new query is executed (which you should see in the logs), and you get all of them, because you did not specify otherwise. The code in your question does not include the place where you do this, but you must be doing it somewhere, in order to get the OfferingSpecials.

Using `includes` asks to eager-load the association, which means that it will be subject to the restrictions of the query, which is why you're seeing it work when you do it that way. It's slower because it's fetching those extra records for you now, instead of doing it separately later.

If you really do want to refactor this using `.joins`, you simply need to add the conditional to the line where you fetch the `.offering_specials` of the Merchant:

```
@merchants.each do |m|
  m.offering_specials.where(:status_code => 'OP')
end
```

However, you should read up on why eager loading exists before doing so - it is likely that either you are already getting better performance by doing one slower query vs. many fast ones, or that you will do so if the number of merchant records involve passes some threshold (which may or may not happen, depending on the nature of your app).

Comment: thanks for the response.  My code is in the controller in an index action.  In the index view I have this: <% @merchants.each do |merchant| %><%= merchant.offering_specials.last.nonprofit_percentage %><% end %>

Comment: So, if, in that line of the view, you add `.where(:status_code => 'OP')` before `.last`, you should get the desired result. You are generating one query for each merchant though, as I said, so check the total page load time to make sure it's actually faster.

Comment: I agree with your overall analysis.  The use of includes in the controller is slower (19ms), but it is faster than separate conditional queries (7ms each).  But I discovered another issue.  By adding the where condition to the includes, it will not retrieve merchants unless they have an open offering special.  Given that I need all merchants, I ended up using this in the controller: @merchants = Merchant.includes(:offering_specials) and this in the index view:   <%= merchant.offering_specials.where(offering_specials: { status_code: "OP" }).last.nonprofit_percentage %>  Thank you MrThWalrus

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted leaner queries with `.includes(...)` as well, and have now released this feature as a part of a data-related gem I maintain, **[The Brick](https://github.com/lorint/brick)**.

By overriding `ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency.apply_column_aliases()` **[like this](https://github.com/lorint/brick/blob/3983b99b3d068834a8d07d44b8749b46b211d41f/lib/brick.rb#L1251-L1310)** then when you add a `.select(...)` then it can act as a filter to choose which column aliases get built out.

With `gem 'brick'` loaded, in order to enable this selective behaviour, add the special column name `:_brick_eager_load` as the first entry in your `.select(...)`, which turns on the filtering of columns while the aliases are being built out.  Here's an example from your merchant offerings data set:

```
@merchants = Merchant.includes(:offering_specials)
                     .references(:offering_specials)
                     .where(offering_specials: { status_code: "OP" })
                     .select(:_brick_eager_load, # Turns on the filtering
                             :name, :slug,
                             'offering_specials.discount_percentage', 
                             'offering_specials.start_at', 'offering_specials.end_at', 'offering_specials.closed_at'
```

Hope it can save you both query time and some RAM!